Azure Devops Linux Agent Powershell
I'm trying to import a custom Powershell module which contains several functions. I would like to use the functions in all the next steps in the pipeline without having to import them every time. Similar to this issue:
Azure DevOps Release Pipeline: Install custom powershell module for use by multiple tasks
But I'm using Linux instead of Windows.
I have copied over the Module to the $Env.PSModulePath and all the sub paths which that variable contains. I verified that the module is there as Microsoft describes it. But I'm not able to use any functions in the steps in the pipeline.
It's good to know that the import function itself contained in the psm1 file does work because I can use the functions in the first step.
Thanks guys!

Can you show the pipeline definition? And if you run whoami command in pipeline, is it the same user with local one? What's Get-Module -ListAvailable output in pipeline?

I can reproduce the same with Ubuntu 22.04 self-hosted agent. I also tested for Microsoft-hosted agent, it works fine.
It was caused by the user permission who run the agent.
Please fix with below steps`:

In agent machine, try to setup services with root permission as per doc:

sudo ./svc.sh install root


Start the service with command:

sudo ./svc.sh start



I have the checkmodule.psm1, need to create same named folder checkmodule under $Env.PSModulePath(/usr/local/share/powershell/Modules) and store the psm1 in the folder(bash task below).


My pipeline below:
trigger: none

pool: SelfHostedAgentPool1

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $env:PSModulePath -split ':'

- bash: |
    sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/powershell/Modules/checkmodule
    sudo cp checkmodule.psm1 /usr/local/share/powershell/Modules/checkmodule/
    ls -al

- pwsh: |
    Get-Module -ListAvailable
  ignoreLASTEXITCODE: true

It can find the module now:

Edit:
Add Microsoft-hosted agent result:


In the case of a Microsoft hosted agent, isn't the svc.sh already running/installed?

For Microsoft-hosted agent, the agent already works as a service, which does not require to run /svc.sh again. The issue happens on self-hosted agent.

Yea exactly, figured as much. But how am I supposed to fix it on a microsoft hosted one then? I copied the module to that specific folder but Powershell is not recognising the module unfortunately

On Microsoft-Hosted agent, you only need to use the sample yaml above, just make sure the folder name is same with your module file, and put the module file under the $Env.PSModulePath(like: /usr/local/share/powershell/Modules/{filenamedfolder}), it will be automatically recognized.  I will edit with result from Microsoft-Hosted agent.

So I ran your pipeline commands and you can see in the logging that the Powershell files were copied to that specific folder:
'src/powershellmodule/SPCTest/TestModule.psm1' -> '/usr/local/share/powershell/Modules/TestModule/TestModule.psm1'
All the other files like the psd1 and the functions are copied with the psm1 as well by the way.
But the following powershell task is still not recognising the module.

Please try: 1. run command Test-ModuleManifest -Path /usr/local/share/powershell/Modules/TestModule/TestModule.psd1 to verify the Module Manifest, make sure the module manifest (.psd1 file) is correctly configured. 2. run command Get-Module -ListAvailable -Refresh to refresh the module cache. If the issue persists, have you checked on local ubuntu machine, do it manually, will it work?

In addition, please change module name TestModule to other name since the name can be got from network directly, to make sure it's from your psm1, use a new name please.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

As confirmed in the discussion, glad to know the issue is resolved. Feel free to raise a new ticket if you have any other queries, thanks.
